# Can <HEAD> tag occur after <BODY> in valid HTML

Tags: html

I tried to load a browser with html file with the  tag after  and it seems to load correctly.

```
<HTML>
 <BODY>
This is body
</BODY>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Does this confirm to HTML specs? The HTML [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) document does not seem to specify the position of the element

In practice, I believe that HEAD will always precede BODY but I don't know if the HTML parsers also implement this positional relationship

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @ctwheels Yeah it should be a duplicate. What does the rules say now; should the question be answered?

Comment: @luxas We now have to wait for a moderator to accept the proposed duplicate as an actual duplicate. See this page for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Sorry this is a duplicate. I did search in the site before posting this. @ctwheels I am not proposing to do that. I just need to understand if I can expect in the real world while handling HTML pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers process markup as it is read - putting a `<head>` element below the `<body>` means that your content will be displayed in an unstyled fashion until the CSS documents linked to in the `<head>`. There's likely to be other issues with this approach.

Also - if you're learning about HTML - skip HTML4.01 and dive on into HTML5 - everyone supports it, and it's pretty normative these days. Learning HTML4.01 is like learning Olde English in the 20th Century.

Anywho - the HTML4.01 manual does say that HEAD must go before BODY - just not in plain English. There is a snippet of the HTML4.01 Strict Document Type Declaration:

```
<!ENTITY % html.content "HEAD, BODY">

<!ELEMENT HTML O O (%html.content;)    -- document root element -->
```

This is the validation rule that says `<html>` must contain a `<head>` and `<body>` in that specific order.

HTML5 doesn't use a doctype - but the standard is more explicitly written for [head](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) and [body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element):

> 4.2.1 The head element
>
> Categories:
>
> None.
>
> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> As the first element in an html element.

...

> 4.3.1 The body element
>
> Categories:
>
> Sectioning root.
>
> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> As the second element in an html element.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Browser will interpret it but it does not mean your code is correct.
you should run your code in the w3c validator https://validator.w3.org/ it will tell you it need to stay in the order html, head, body

Comment: But it would be so much easier to do certain things - for example, React SSR where you need to process the entire tree before you output things like <title> or other style attributes (material-ui). If we could output that stuff after the fact, then we could renderToNodeStream more easily, without having to cache anything. Who do we need to talk to to change this?!